# How can you prevent a Python generator function from omitting the last item?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am currently trying to parse a large file that contains several XML files concatenated within. I am currently able to get every item in a valid XML format except for the last one. I decided to try my function that includes only a subset of 4 concatenated XML files.

The function is the following:

```
def read_bulk_file(bulk_file): #better name pending
with open(bulk_file, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    document = ''
    document += '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n'
    n = 1
    for line in f:
        if '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>' in line:
            print('Sending batch ' + str(n) + '...', end='')
            yield document
            print('Success!')
            n += 1
            print('Resetting document for item ' + str(n) + '...', end='')
            document = ''
            print('Success!')
            print('Adding xml declaration tag for item ' + str (n) + '...', end='')
            document += '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n'
            print('Success!')
        else:
            document += line
```

The script that I use to run my function is:

```
text_generator = read_bulk_file('./Data/test_xml.xml')
n = 1
while True:
    try:
        print('Reading Item #' + str(n) + ': ', end='')
        n += 1
        with open('./Data/results/item' + str(n-1) + '.xml', 'w') as o:
             o.write(next(text_generator))
        print('You have created item file #' + str(n-1) + '!')
    except StopIteration:
        print('Generator function didn\'t find more items!')
        break
```

Finally, the output in the console is:

> Reading Item #1: Sending batch 1...You have created item file #1!
>
> Reading Item #2: Success!
>
> Resetting document for item 2...Success!
>
> Adding xml declaration tag for item 2...Success!
>
> Sending batch 2...You have created item file #2!
>
> Reading Item #3: Success!
>
> Resetting document for item 3...Success!
>
> Adding xml declaration tag for item 3...Success!
>
> Sending batch 3...You have created item file #3!
>
> Reading Item #4: Success!
>
> Resetting document for item 4...Success!
>
> Adding xml declaration tag for item 4...Success!
>
> Generator function didn't find more items!

As you can see, a file is not created for item 4. I am almost certain that this has to do with the StopIteration exception being thrown.

I double checked that the file was being read until the end of it, and it seemed like that was the case and, therefore, I would assume that the document variable existed up until that moment, right before the exception was thrown.

Is there a way to get the contents of the last iteration before the exception is raised?

Comment: Why not increment n after the writing (in your harness)?

Comment: *"omitting the last item?"*: As you `yield` **not** if `document` has finished. Your condition is ***`yield` document if read new header==`<?xml...`***. Change your condition or simple do `return document` after `for line ...`.

Comment: @Riker Yup, it makes more sense, I've fixed that now!

Comment: @stovfl do you mean adding `return document` outside of the for loop or as the first line within the loop?

Comment: @stovfl I tried printing the last document right after the for loop and confirmed it exists before it goes back to the main script. However, adding `return document` still didn't pass the content of the last document to the write statement.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by adding a `yield document` right after the for loop. This created an additional empty file, but I removed it during the `except` section. Thanks for the help!